# How to create a table in R that includes column totals

Tags: r, statistics

I'm somewhat new to R programming and am in need of assistance.

I'm looking to take the sum of 4 columns in a dataframe and list these totals in a simple table.

Essentially, take the sum of 4 columns (A, B, C, D) and list the total in a table (table = column 1: A, B, C, D column 2: sum of column A, B, C, D) - something along the lines of:

- A = 3
- B = 4
- C = 4
- D = 3

Does anyone know how to get this output?  Also, the less "manual" the response, the better (i.e. trying to avoid having to input several lines of code to get this output if possible).

Thank you.

Comment: Please show few lines of your input dataset and expected result based on that.  Perhaps `?colSums` help

Answer (score 1):

If your data looks like this:

```
a <- c(1:4)
b <- c(2:5)
c <- c(3:6)
d <- c(4:7)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

  a b c d
1 1 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 4 5 6
4 4 5 6 7
```

Use

```
> res <- sapply(df,sum)
```

to get

```
 a  b  c  d 
10 14 18 22
```

in order to apply the function only on numeric columns, try

```
> res <- colSums(df[sapply(df,is.numeric)])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `colSums`:

```
colSums(Filter(is.numeric, df))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  What if the columns do not all contain numbers (i.e. the columns contained text, not a numeric factor).  Would this function still work?

Comment: What would you expect as the output?

Comment: I would expect numeric values.  Essentially, it would be similar to using a countif function in excel (using a text factor as the "countif" target).

Comment: in order to test the whole column, you could try 
`colSums(df[sapply(df,is.numeric)])` then it will only summarise the columns where all values are numeric

Comment: what if I wanted to only summarize the cells within columns that contained text, not numeric values?  Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer to only count the numeric columns.